# Do I have scoping issues?

Tags: python

Here's my code, I can't seem to get any of my values to be modified from the assignment at the input statements. Is there some scoping rules I'm not familiar with from Python?

```
    days=0
    airfaire=0
    mealsPaid=0
    carRental=0
    privateMilesDriven=0
    parkingFees=0
    taxiCharges=0
    conferenceFees=0
    lodgingCharges=0

    def getInputForVariables():
        days=input("Number of days on the trip: ")
        airfaire=input("Amount of airfare, if none then enter 0: ")
        mealsPaid=input("Amount paid for meals, if none then enter 0: ")
        carRental=input("Amount of car rental fees, if none then enter 0: ")
        privateMilesDriven=input("Number of miles driven, if a private vehicle was used: ")
        parkingFees=input("Amount of parking fees, if none then enter 0: ")
        taxiCharges=input("Amount of taxi charges, if none then enter 0: ")
        conferenceFees=input("Conference or seminar registration fees, if none then enter 0: ")
        lodgingCharges=input("Lodging charges, per night: ")


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        getInputForVariables()
        print("the number of days is", days)
        print("the amount of lodginnig charges is", (lodgingCharges))
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, you are creating local variables in your function. Btw. there can't be many languages that handle this differently because if all names from each function were to leak out that wouldd just be an unholy mess. If you want your function to take any effect you have to return the values or declare the variables global (not recommended) or pack them in a mutable container object like dictionary. These are passed "by reference" in python, so you can modify them and the effects will be visible to all variables holding a reference.

Comment: Follow python naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are scoping issues with your code. The function `getInputForVariables` only has the variable(s) defined in the scope of the function itself. After the call to the function ends the variable values are discarded. What you may want to do is store the inputs into a dictionary and return that

```
def getInputForVariables():
    data={}
    data["days"]=input("Number of days on the trip: ")
    data["airfaire"]=input("Amount of airfare, if none then enter 0: ")
    data["mealsPaid"]=input("Amount paid for meals, if none then enter 0: ")
    data["carRental"]=input("Amount of car rental fees, if none then enter 0: ")
    data["privateMilesDriven"]=input("Number of miles driven, if a private vehicle was used: ")
    data["parkingFees"]=input("Amount of parking fees, if none then enter 0: ")
    data["taxiCharges"]=input("Amount of taxi charges, if none then enter 0: ")
    data["conferenceFees"]=input("Conference or seminar registration fees, if none then enter 0: ")
    data["lodgingCharges"]=input("Lodging charges, per night: ")
    return data
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data=getInputForVariables()
    print("the number of days is", data["days"])
    print("the amount of lodginnig charges is", (data["lodgingCharges"]
```

This way you can access the input data from the returned value and get the input by way of `data["insert variable name here"]`.